# Create multidimensional array in foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a foreach that checks multiple requests via API and selects only those requests that have items with the prefix of sku == "MCA". However, as I've done below, I can only put a single order in the array, when I'd have to place all the requests.

```
foreach($listaPedidos as $pedido) :
    $i = 0;
    $somatorio = array();

    $resulta = $client->salesOrderInfo($session, $pedido->increment_id);
    foreach($resulta->items as $item) :
        $sku = $item->sku;
        if (substr($sku, 0,3) == "MCA") :
            $email = $pedido->customer_email;
            $codCli = idClienteMca($conn, $session, $client, $email);
            $dataCadastro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $qtdItens = ++$i;
            $somatorio[] = (float)$item->row_total;
            $totalPedido = array_sum($somatorio);
            $observacao = "";
            $boleto = "0";
            $transportadora = "";

            $todosPedidos = array(
                "codcli"        => $codCli,
                "datacadastro"  => $dataCadastro,
                "qtditens"      => $qtdItens,
                "totalpedido"   => $totalPedido,
                "observacao"    => $observacao,
                "boleto"        => $boleto
            );

        endif;
    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

The result I expected would be this:

```
array(2) {
  array(6) {
    ["codcli"]=>
    string(3) "576"
    ["datacadastro"]=>
    string(19) "2017-12-28 17:22:24"
    ["qtditens"]=>
    int(3)
    ["totalpedido"]=>
    float(74.19)
    ["observacao"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["boleto"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  array(6) {
    ["codcli"]=>
    string(3) "890"
    ["datacadastro"]=>
    string(19) "2017-12-28 17:55:24"
    ["qtditens"]=>
    int(4)
    ["totalpedido"]=>
    float(154.89)
    ["observacao"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["boleto"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

How do I bring all the requests, not just the last iteration?

Tks!

Comment: English language pls

Comment: @tadman excuse me. Changed for english

Comment: One thing to note here is the use of `if ... :` and `endif` is fairly non-standard. While valid, most code bases use the conventional `if { ... }` structure instead if only because it's less verbose.

Comment: Tks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Problem*** You are over-writing `$todosPedidos` variable inside `foreach()` again and again, and that's why you got only the last result.

***Solution:-***

1. define `$todosPedidos = [];` before first `foreach()`.
2. Change `$todosPedidos` to `$todosPedidos[]`

So code needs to be:-

```
$todosPedidos = [];
foreach($listaPedidos as $pedido) :
    $i = 0;
    $somatorio = array();

    $resulta = $client->salesOrderInfo($session, $pedido->increment_id);
    foreach($resulta->items as $item) :
        $sku = $item->sku;
        if (substr($sku, 0,3) == "MCA") :
            $email = $pedido->customer_email;
            $codCli = idClienteMca($conn, $session, $client, $email);
            $dataCadastro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $qtdItens = ++$i;
            $somatorio[] = (float)$item->row_total;
            $totalPedido = array_sum($somatorio);
            $observacao = "";
            $boleto = "0";
            $transportadora = "";

            $todosPedidos[] = array(
                "codcli"        => $codCli,
                "datacadastro"  => $dataCadastro,
                "qtditens"      => $qtdItens,
                "totalpedido"   => $totalPedido,
                "observacao"    => $observacao,
                "boleto"        => $boleto
            );

        endif;
    endforeach;

endforeach;
print_r($todosPedidos); // to check that all data coming or not?
```

Comment: But the result was not yet expected. Now the answer was 6 arrays and I expected only 2. I have 2 equal orders in the database and I need to write in the array mainly the total of items and also the total value of the request. But that way the result was a loop for each product. I need a loop per order.